# How to submit to controller with arguments?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, post, form-submit

I'm trying to auto submit on dropdownlist change to my controller with arguments. The POST does happen but I only get this error

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'category' of non-nullable type   'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult Index(System.String, System.String, Int32)' in 'shopping.WebUI.Controllers.HomeController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter. Parameter name: parameters

I have a JQuery script

```
$(".autoSubmit select").change(function () {
    $(this).closest('form').submit();
});
```

a form on my View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.Action("ShipToCountry", "Filters", new { Model.SelectedCountry })
}
```

but need to POST to this action

```
[HttpPost]
public ViewResult Index(string country, string currency, int category)
{
    var viewModel = new MainViewModel
    {
        SelectedCountry = country,
        SelectedCurrency = currency,
        Categories = category }
    };
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

None of the country, currency, category arguments is or can be optional.

What changes do I need to make, on the View maybe, to pass those parameters to the Action?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error states that your `category` parameter of `Index` view is NULL. You either have to change the HTML and javascript so that the `category` parameter gets value before posting or you can change the POST method to make `category` optional like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ViewResult Index(string country, string currency, int? category)
{
    var viewModel = new MainViewModel
    {
        SelectedCountry = country,
        SelectedCurrency = currency,
        Categories = category }
    };
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

---

EDIT:

Since you can't make parameters optional, you have to ensure in your HTML that before doing the POST, all `<input>` and `<select>` elements are correctly filled (and correctly named if they already aren't).

In your case, the problem is with the category parameter. Assuming that the select that auto-submits is also the dropdown list of categories, you need to assure that the outputted  HTML is similar to this:

```
<select name="category">
    <option value="1">Category 1</option>
    <option value="2">Category 2</option>
    <option value="3">Category 3</option>
</select>
```

The key here is that select **MUST** have the name `category` (or you should rename the parameter `category` in the `Index` method to match the name of this select) and that options **MUST** have integer values.

---

EDIT 2:

To add the currency and category, you need to add `<input name="currency">` and `<input name="category">` fields to the same `<form>` where your country is. Note, that it doesn't need to be `<input>` specifically, it could be `<select>` as well, but the field's `name` must be the same as the name of parameters in `Index` method.

Comment: The ddl is rendered as:

    <select id="ShipToCountry" name="ShipToCountry">
    <option value="DZ">Algeria</option>
    <option value="AO">Angola</option>
    <option value="AG">Antigua</option>
    ...

the id is the country code and that is fine. I need to make changes to populate currency and category. How/where can I add those?

Comment: Hidden Input fields is what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Either include some input with a name of "category" or make the category parameter nullable
e.g `public ViewResult Index(string country, string currency, int? category)`

If your dropdowns is the aforementioned "category" input make sure that it has an actual value before posting the form.